# Angular 2, ngFor create a new context for each iteration?

Tags: angular, ngfor

Everyone!
In Angular 2,  *ngFor create a new context for each iteration? like ng-repeat in angular js?. I need to change a variable value inside *ngFor, but that value change for all iterations. Example:

```html
<div *ngFor="let label of labels">
    <div class="company"><a (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed;isCollapsed ?                       labelStyle = {color: 'gray'}:labelStyle = {color: '#337ab7'}"                       [ngStyle]="labelStyle">{{label}}</a>
     </div>
     <div [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
         <div class="item" *ngFor="let product of products">
            <div class="meta" *ngIf="product.year == label">
              <div class="details">
                <div [innerHTML]=product.reference></div>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

When I do click on a label, **isCollapsed** change from false to true, but **isCollpsed** change for all iterations. Could you give me an advice for doing click and collapsing only one label?

Thanks

Comment: I think there has to be a way to uniquely identify which div you want to collapse. Maybe use 'isCollapsed + label' if label is always unique.

Comment: `label` and `product` change within each context, but values from outside (if you access a member from the components class, it will be the same for each context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add isCollapsed as a property of class used by labels.

In your component, if your 'labels' is a number array, i.e. if it is currently:

```
labels: number[]
```

then change it to

```
labels: MyLabel[]
```

and after your component class add a model called `MyLabel` like:

```
class MyLabel{
   constructor(public year: number, public isCollapsed: boolean){}
}
```

And then in the html you could use it like:

```
<div *ngFor="let label of labels">
<div class="company"><a (click)="label.isCollapsed = !label.isCollapsed                     labelStyle = {color: 'gray'}:labelStyle = {color: '#337ab7'}"                       [ngStyle]="labelStyle">{{label.year}}</a>
 </div>
 <div [ngbCollapse]="label.isCollapsed">
     <div class="item" *ngFor="let product of products">
        <div class="meta" *ngIf="product.year === label.year">
          <div class="details">
            <div [innerHTML]=product.reference></div>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `label.isCollapsed = !label.isCollapsed`?

Answer (score 0):

You can define one field in component with `index` name and set it to `null` and using `$index` like this:

```
<div class="company"><a (click)="toggleCollapsed($index) ? labelStyle = {color: 'gray'}:labelStyle = {color: '#337ab7'}"                       [ngStyle]="labelStyle">{{label.year}}</a>
```

And define toggleCollapsed(index) as follow:

```
toggleCollapsed(index : number){
    this.index != index ? this.index = index : this.index = null;
    return this.index == index;
}
```